# put tabPanel forward: best method?

Tags: xpages, tabpanel

i tried this with sessionScope (didn't work):

The following Tabs should be controllable with the help of variable 'm1':

```xml
<xp:tabbedPanel id="tabbedPanel1"
    selectedTab="#{javascript:sessionScope.get('m1')}">
    <xp:tabPanel label="Config" id="conf">
        <xc:k_conf></xc:k_conf>
    </xp:tabPanel>
    <xp:tabPanel label="Solution" id="sol">
        <xc:k_sol></xc:k_sol>
    </xp:tabPanel>
</xp:tabbedPanel>
```

In Control k_conf is a button 'calculate' which performs an agent and then sets the varable 'm1' to 'sol'.
I would expect, that the Tab switches to 'Solution', but nothing happens (although refreshmode="complete").

```xml
<xp:button value="calculate" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        ...
        <xp:executeScript>
            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:
                ...
                agent.runWithDocumentContext(docVG.getDocument());
                sessionScope.put("m1","sol");
                }]]>
        </xp:this.script>
    </xp:executeScript>
    ...
</xp:button>
```

Another approach was to use component (didn't work because 'show is not allowed for TabPanel'):

```xml
 <xp:this.action>
   <![CDATA[#{javascript:
         var c = getComponent("IdofTab");
         c.show("IdofTab");
      }]]>
 </xp:this.action>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That sessionScope approach should work, I just tried it and verified that. Is there some CSJS part to the button eventHandler that is not returning true and thus preventing the SSJS executeScript from being performed?

For the second approach, you can use the `setSelectedTab` method of the tabbed panel rather than `show`, for example:

```
<xp:button id="button2" value="Change Tab 4">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action>
            <![CDATA[#{javascript:
                 var c = getComponent("tabbedPanel1");
                 c.setSelectedTab("tabPanel4");
              }]]>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Comment: The c.setSelectedTab approach works. Thank you Brian !

Comment: Cool. FYI stackoverflow etiquette is to "accept" an answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235, http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer